# php - mysql update inside a loop using checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to update all selected fields in the database using check box. This is the code that I've done, but it only updates the last record I choose from the checkbox list.

```
<tbody>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryEmail)):?>
<tr>    
<td><input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value=<?php echo $row['id'];?>> 
</td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['hour'];?></td>             
</tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
</tbody>
<?php
$hor = $_POST['hours']; //input value i want to update in selected id's
foreach ($_POST['formDoor'] as $entry){  
$sql = "UPDATE hora SET hour='$hor' WHERE id = $entry";  
}
?>
```

Comment: You must execute the query each time or you will only run it the last time through the loop.

Comment: your code does not show were you run your query, but i'm betting its outside the loop, were it should be inside. you also have security issues, so dont use this in a real site

Comment: this is the query $sql = "UPDATE hora SET hour='$hor' WHERE id = $entry"; is inside the foreach

Comment: that's just assigning the query to a string, its not being run there

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this You are forget to execute mysqli_query() on loop

```
<tbody>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryEmail)):?>
    <tr>    
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="formDoor[]" value=<?php echo $row['id'];?>> 
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['hour'];?></td>             
    </tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
</tbody>

<?php
$hor = $_POST['hours']; //input value i want to update in selected id's
foreach ($_POST['formDoor'] as $entry){  
   $sql = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE hora SET hour='$hor' WHERE id = $entry");     
}    
?>
```

Comment: invalid syntax, `mysqli_query` requires 2 arguments

Comment: I have just edited my comment use $conn make sure you are use $con on your connection.php

Comment: This might "work" but it's actually a huge liability since raw `$_POST` data is [injected into the query](http://bobby-tables.com/). This can be fixed by using prepared statements with placeholder values. It wasn't a vulnerability before, that `$sql` code did nothing, but now it's been weaponized by this fix.